# Unable to load resource using Thymeleaf View Layer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf view layer for the first time. I have changed the default location of templates to `WEB-INF/views` and all my static resources sit under `/resources/css/` directory which are mapped to `/css/**` pattern using a spring resource handler. I have a page that make use of CSS files which fails during runtime. I get below exception. If I remove `<link>` tags the page loads without any `CSS` applied. Below is the link i have in the page

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.min.css}">`

Resource handlers:

```
@Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/js/");
 }
```

Exception:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter execution threw an exception
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:135)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:104)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:135)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:104)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:85)
    org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter.handleException(ErrorPageFilter.java:135)
```

Comment: The excerpt from the stacktrace doesn't indicate what's wrong. Can you post the complete stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

You are using spring boot, you don't need override `addResourceHandlers(..)`, just put you resources in `src/main/resources/static` or `src/main/resources/public` or `src/main/resources/resources`, these folders are registered by default in spring boot.

update:
then put it on /WEB-INF/static or WEB-INF/resources or WEB-INF/public

Comment: But I don't want to put WEB related resources under `src/main/resources`. I would like to put `CSS` related stuff inside `/webapp/resources/css`. How can I configure ThymeLeaf to read resources from that location?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I managed to get that part working. But now I'm running into a very strange StackOverflow error where the page doesn't work if I include a simple static twitter bootstrap code snippet. I don't understand the nature of problem.